# How to create a css hover effect for show button

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm trying to create a card with a hover effect. When hovering over the card, I would like to add an opacity to the card and show 4 buttons, one above the other. Can you help me?

Below is my code.

```css
.cardnew {
  height          : 256px;
  text-align      : center;
  width           : 246px;
  background      : #ffffff;
  margin          : 20px;
  display         : inline-block;
  box-shadow      : 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
  border-radius   : 1px;
  cursor          : pointer;
  transition      : 0.15s linear;
  }
.cardnew > img {
  height          : 150px;
  width           : 100%;
  border-radius   : 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding         : 35px 0 5px 0;
  }
.cardnew > h1 {
  font-size       : 22px;
  color           : #5c5c5c;
  padding         : 15px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight     : 100;
  }
.cardnew > p {
  font-size       : 13px;
  color           : #cdcdcd;
  padding         : 0 40px;
  line-height     : 20px;
  }
.cardnew > a {
  padding         : 13px;
  font-weight     : normal;
  width           : 260px;
  color           : #2687f1;
  border          : 2px solid #2687f1;
  border-radius   : 7px;
  margin          : auto;
  margin-top      : 35px;
  display         : block;
  transition      : 0.2s linear;
  }
.cardnew:hover {
  transform       : scale(1.015);
  transition      : 0.15s linear;
  box-shadow      : 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.5);
  }
.cardnew:hover > a {
  padding         : 13px;
  width           : 260px;
  color           : #fff;
  background      : #2687f1;
  border-radius   : 7px;
  margin          : auto;
  margin-top      : 35px;
  transition      : 0.2s linear;
  }
.row-card {
  justify-content : space-around;
  flex-wrap       : wrap;
  margin-right    : -12.5px;
  margin-left     : -12.5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row-card">
    <div class="cardnew">
      <img src="https://enginehosting-html.fruitfulcode.com/wp-content/themes/enginehosting-html/assets/images/server.svg" style="padding: 60px 0 5px 0;height: 125px;" />
      <h1>
        name 
      </h1>
      <p>firstname</p>
      <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried some tutorials that I found on MDN and youtube but I couldn't implement it. Any help will be of great help.
can you help me?

like this pen: https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

Comment: If you want change opactiy, just put opacity in you hover selector, like `.cardnew:hover {opacity: 0.5;}`, and remove the `transition` declaration because you have already do it in your `.cardnew` selector

Comment: @iulo Hello, how are you? The opacity that I can put, but how can I hide and show the buttons on the hover card only? The 4 buttons one above the other centered on the card?

Comment: You can use JS, addEventListener("mouseover", ...), than when the mouse pointer will be inside the card you can change the display of you buttons. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Part of your problem, I'm sure, is that you're using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`) in your selector: `.cardnew > a`. That selector would match if the links were direct children of `.cardnew`, but in your HTML they're children of `.button` elements. It looks to me like all of your code would work without the child combinators. In fact, all I did at [this pen](https://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/RwGvGyQ) is remove them and it seems like it might be closer to what you wanted.

Comment: @Vince 
this, what I would like to leave the buttons hidden. And display the buttons inside the card centered inside the card in the hover of the card. I managed to put an opacity on the card but did not adjust the buttons in the center of the card on the hover.

Comment: @Vince i try this:

<div class="buttons">
        <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
          <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
            <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
              <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
      </div>

 .button {
    display: none;
  }

  .cardnew:hover .button {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #2687f1;
    color: black;
  }

  .buttons {
    margin-top: -150px;
  }

and my style don't work.

Comment: @Vince Like this pen https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

Comment: simply give the button the css property and value `display: none;` if you hover the card, use the `:hover` selector to change them to `display: block;`

Comment: @tacoshy 
Hello, I tried this, and my style was all broken, as in the code above. I'm trying exactly like on the pen https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

Comment: this is because you have a very messed up css and espacially overflowing as you have no responsivness in mind by declaring fixed values.  add 2 drawings, one of the intended layout normally and 1 on hover. So we could start over from scratch and do it clean.

Comment: @tacoshy 
I need the card hover to look like the image 
https://imgur.com/a/gIwaGhr exactly this pen codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the styling for the buttons wasn't applied is because of all the `>`s you had. If you remove them, it seems to work a lot better. Also, you have a lot of `div`s that aren't closed at the bottom. Is there a reason for that?

For the disappearing, you can use the `opacity` property to make them disappear and reappear on hover.

```css
.cardnew {
  height: 256px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 246px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.15s linear;
}

.cardnew img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 35px 0 5px 0;
}

.cardnew h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.cardnew p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 0 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cardnew a {
  padding: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 260px;
  color: #2687f1;
  border: 2px solid #2687f1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.cardnew:hover {
  transform: scale(1.015);
  transition: 0.15s linear;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.5);
}

.cardnew:hover a {
  padding: 13px;
  width: 260px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2687f1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.row-card {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -12.5px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-card">
  <div class="cardnew">
    <img src="https://enginehosting-html.fruitfulcode.com/wp-content/themes/enginehosting-html/assets/images/server.svg" style="padding: 60px 0 5px 0;height: 125px;" />
    <h1>
      name
    </h1>
    <p>firstname</p>
    <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
        <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
          <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT:**
I have messed around with your code, and I think I have created something like your picture.

(You might need to mess around with the values to get them perfect.)

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 256px;
  width: 246px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.cardnew a {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 160px;
  color: #2687f1;
  border: 2px solid #2687f1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.cardnew:hover a {
  transform: scale(1);
  padding: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2687f1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.btn1 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 42.5px;
}

.btn2 {
  top: 65px;
  left: 42.5px;
}

.btn3 {
  top: 120px;
  left: 42.5px;
}

.btn4 {
  top: 175px;
  left: 42.5px;
}

.cardnew {
  height: 256px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 246px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.15s linear;
}

.cardnew img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 35px 0 5px 0;
}

.cardnew h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.cardnew p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 0 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

..cardnew:hover {
  transform: scale(1.015);
  transition: 0.15s linear;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.5);
}

.cardnew:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row-card {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -12.5px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-card">
  <div class="cardnew">
    <div class='overlay'>
    </div>
    <img src="https://enginehosting-html.fruitfulcode.com/wp-content/themes/enginehosting-html/assets/images/server.svg" style="padding: 60px 0 5px 0;height: 125px;" />
    <h1>
      name
    </h1>
    <p>firstname</p>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="btn1"> BUTTON </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="btn2"> BUTTON </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="btn3"> BUTTON </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="btn4"> BUTTON </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen: [click here](https://codepen.io/bobsfriend/pen/vYXbyJv)

Comment: Hello, I tried this, and my style was all broken, as in the code above. I'm trying exactly like on the pen https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

I would like to leave the buttons inside the card, centered on card hover.

Comment: Are you wanting to increase the height of the card on hover? Or just move what is already in the card?

Comment: I would like the buttons to be centered inside the card on the hover, and add an opacity so that the contents of the card disappear, and show only the buttons inside the card.

I tried:
.card: hover {
background: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.1;
}

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think you want.

Comment: wow, it's what you needed. I'm trying to put a spacing between the buttons, but I'm not getting it, can you tell me why? I wanted to leave at least 5px of space on each button, my css is not accepting.

Comment: @Dave to change the space between the buttons you have to change the `top` values under the `.btn1` to `.btn4` classes that I added.